# Getting the index of the newly inserted element into a array

Tags: php, arrays

let's say I insert a element into a array like this:

`$arr[] = 'something';`

how can I get the index of 'something' ?

is there any other method I can insert a element in the array and know the index of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try end() it will work fine,,

```
$fruits = array('apple', 'banana', 'cranberry');
echo end($fruits); // cranberry
```

Answer (score 4):

The following will work if there are breaks in the indexes:

```
$arr = array('ASD', 'QWE', 5 => 'JKL');
$arr[] = 'ZXC';
end($arr);
$new_index = key($arr); // 6
```

Answer (score 2):

If you always insert elements like this the index will be:

```
count($arr) - 1
```

you can insert elements like this to know their index:

```
$arr['somekey'] = 'something';
```

Alternatively you could also use array_search() (http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) but that might not be ideal as you can have same elements multiple times inside an array.

Comment: Note: that will not work if there are skips in the array's indexing.